# ASP.NET Core 2.0 URL rewriting in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a client that's converting from a PHP system to a .NET system.  One requirement is that certain legacy system URLs ending in ".php" are still accessible in the new .NET environment.

Essentially I need to map arbitrary string paths to specific Controllers/Actions.

Can anyone tell me what the recommended and most performant approach is in ASP.NET Core 2.0 to handle this scenario?  Custom middleware?  Introduce a Web.Config?  Action attributes in the controller?

Are there any "gotchas" I should be on the lookout for?

The site is hosted in Azure, if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, if I try to visit an old URL of http://yoursite.com/somepage.php, do you want to preserve that URL with the .php extension and serve a .NET generated page? Or do you want to 301 redirect to a new page, such as http://yoursite.com/somepage ?

Comment: Yes, I want to preserve that URL without a redirect.  I believe if I wanted the 301 redirect, the best way to do that would be through IIS rewrites, yea?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what the recommended and most performant approach is in ASP.NET Core 2.0 to handle this scenario? Custom middleware? Introduce a Web.Config? Action attributes in the controller?

I assume that you could leverage [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and read the related tutorials. I just checked it and added the URL rewrite rule under my azure web app via  the [Azure App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx) as follows:

[image]

**TEST:**

[image]

Additionally, you could also write the URL rewrite rules in your code, details you could follow [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).